# Could not find "store" in either the context or props of

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am just starting to learn react (and I find it very confusing) and I am trying to get the following page to render:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Header from '../components/Header';
import { saveRepos } from "../actions/AppActions";


class Search extends React.Component {

  state = {
    search: ""
  };

  searchGithub = () => {
    fetch("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=" + this.state.search)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(respJson => {
        this.props.dispatch(saveRepos(respJson.items));
      });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.searchGithub();
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
          <Header title="Search" />
          <hr />
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="search"
              value=""
              onChange={search => {
                this.setState({ search: search.target.value });
              }}
            />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
          </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    repos: state.repos
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Search);
```

I was able to render the page by building Search as a const but as soon as I converted it to a class and used export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Search); instead of export default Search I started receiving the could not find "store"... error message.  I'm not really sure how this thing is supposed to work.  I did try adding a  pair around the  but I still get the same error.

Thank you for any assistance.

Jonathan

Note: The original post had the line 
    onChange={search2 => {
                this.setState({ search: search.target.value });

I have changed this to 
    onChange={search => {
                this.setState({ search: search.target.value });

In addition, here is my main_page.js which is launched when I start the project:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { Home, Edit, Search, Github, Mine, About } from "./screens";

const Index = ({ store }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
        <Route path="/edit" component={Edit} />
        <Route path="/search" component={Search} />
        <Route path="/github" component={Github} />
        <Route path="/mine" component={Mine} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider> 
);


render(<Index />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: is your top level component a child of `<Provider>`?

Comment: Being new to reach, I'm not really sure what you mean. Since I con't have <Provider> anywhere in this file, I can only assume by your comment that I am supposed to have that somewhere else. I have the file that executes when the project starts that has the routes to each component and yes, there is <Provider store={store} in that file.

Comment: Is your whole component hierarchy surrounded by the `<Provider>` component, is this component a child of the `<Provider>`

Comment: I just updated my post with the code from an additional file.  From reading through the answer provided by @javascriptonian I would say yes, my component hierarchy is surrounded by the <Provider> component.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use the `Provider` tag over your top level component and pass it a `store` which is created using `createStore` as in the source code shown below.

This is an example from the official redux documentation page.

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import todoApp from './reducers'
import App from './components/App'
 
let store = createStore(todoApp)
 
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#passing-the-store

---

Based on your code that you added to your question, the `store` object in `const Index = ({ store }) => ( ... )` is `undefined`, that's why you're getting that error. You have to create the `store` object with `createStore` imported from the `redux` module. So your code should look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducers from './reducers'
import { Home, Edit, Search, Github, Mine, About } from "./screens";

const store = createStore(reducers)

const Index = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
        <Route path="/edit" component={Edit} />
        <Route path="/search" component={Search} />
        <Route path="/github" component={Github} />
        <Route path="/mine" component={Mine} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider> 
);


render(<Index />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I added the import reducers, the const store = ... and const reducers = .... and got it to work!  Thanks for all the help. I used some sample code to build the const reducers = ...... component.  Do the reducers serve a purpose or is it just needed to satisfy the syntax?

Comment: The reducers are supposed to specify how the application's state changes in response to actions sent to the store. It's crucial to the redux architecture. If the answer solved your problem, please check it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Index` component takes a `store` prop which you are not passing it.

> `const Index = ({ store }) => (...`
>
> `render(<Index />, document.getElementById('root'));`  // not passing `store`

Be sure to call `createStore` and pass it as a prop.